# Crear ABB de manera iterativa C++

Tags: c++

tengo el siguiente codigo que compila perfecto, pero al ejecutarse e imprimir el arbol, el mismo se encuentra vacío.

```
void arbol::ArbolBusqI(string x, pnodo& nuevo)
{
    pnodo ptr = nuevo;
    for (;;)
  {
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            ptr = new nodoArbol();
            ptr->info = x;
            ptr->izq=ptr->der=NULL;
            ptr->repe=1;
            return; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (ptr->info==x)
            {
                ptr->repe++;
                return;
            }
            if (x < ptr->info)
                ptr = ptr->izq;
            if (x > ptr->info)
                ptr = ptr->der;
    }
  }
}
```

pnodo es un tipo de dato que basicamente es un puntero a nodoArbol.ademas, cuando se ingresa un dato repetido, se aumenta la repeticion del nodo (int repe) en 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el siguiente fragmento creas un nuevo nodo para el arbol...

```
if (ptr == NULL)
{
  ptr = new nodoArbol();
  ptr->info = x;
  ptr->izq=ptr->der=NULL;
  ptr->repe=1;
  return; 
}
```

... pero si te fijas no estás incluyendo dicho nodo en el arbol, por lo que el mismo siempre se va a encontrar vacío.

Para añadir el nodo al arbol necesitas mantener un puntero al nodo *padre*. Si te puedes permitir el lujo de editar los constructores de los objetos lo más recomendable es, lo primero antes de nada, tocar el constructor para que deje sus variables miembro inicializadas:

```
struct nodoArbol
{
  nodoArbol(std::string const& info)
    : info(info), izq(0), der(0), repe(1)
  { }

  // ...
};
```

Si no puedes hacer esto entonces lo ideal es habilitar una función que haga justamente eso:

```
pnodo NuevoNodo(std::string const& info)
{
  pnodo nodo = new nodoArbol(x);
  nodo->info = info;
  nodo->izq = 0;
  nodo->der = 0;
  nodo->repe = 1;
}
```

Y ahora ya podemos modificar la función para que se puedan añadir los nodos al arbol:

```
if( nuevo == 0 )
  nuevo = new nodoArbol(x);
else
{
  pnodo ptr = nuevo;
  while( true )
  {
    if( x == ptr->info )
    {
      nuevo->repe++;
      return;
    }
    else if( ptr->info > x )
    {
      if( ptr->izq )
        ptr = ptr->izq;
      else
      {
        ptr->izq = new nodoArbol(x);
        return;
      }
    } else { // ptr->info < x
      if( ptr->der)
        ptr = ptr->der;
      else
      {
        ptr->der= new nodoArbol(x);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: buenisimo! gracias, me sirvió